# I can't create Xamarin.Forms project on Visual studio 22

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have problem with Vs22. I can t create Xamarin.Forms project. When i m trying to create project i have Error The system cannot find specified file.(Exception from HRESULT:0x80070002).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUvlf.png)

I tried to reinstall Xamarin in vs installer and repair.

Comment: Maybe like this ? https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/13676

Comment: Please translate the exception message in image, to English. Include that as text.

Comment: Its translated in line 2 The system cannot find specified file.(Exception from HRESULT:0x80070002).

Comment: If there is no other way, you can try to perform [a through uninstall for Xamarin for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/uninstall-xamarin-vs) and then reinstall it.

Comment: Still same result, i will try to reinstall whole vs

Comment: @Tak Is it valid after reinstalling vs?

Comment: Nope, I fixed it by opening solution that was created by my friend, idk why but now its working propely

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it turned out that the installation of the entire ".NET Multi-platform App UI development" bundle (with selected optional checkbox "Xamarin") was required to create a new project.

I initially wanted to install Xamarin itself as an individual component, which resulted in an identical error.

Instructions with screenshots are available in Microsoft's documentation presented below.

[Installing Xamarin on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/installation/?pivots=windows-vs2022)

I believe this may solve your problem.

Comment: Opening the Visual Studio Community installer, choosing the modify option, selecting the ".NET Multi-platform App UI development" option and installing fixed the errors and restored my happiness. Thank you very much CasualDeveloper.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, opening Visual Studio 2022 and using 'Run as Administrator' got me past it.

Comment: Your answer is good and expresses how you used it in the past. That's awesome. If you split this answer into two sentences, your answer will be clearer. As it, it's hard to read and takes a while to get the meaning.  (You of course know what you mean but another person needs to parse out the clauses in the complex sentence.) I used XML to express the template for illustrative purposes. (I'm not saying use this template all of the time but it defiantly is suitable for this case.)
<background> I had this problem...</background> <- one sentence. <solution>Run as administrator....</solution>

Keep

Comment: Hi Lance, Thanks noted, I've re-worded so as to give better clarity.